# Portfolio Turnover with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compute the portfolio turnover for a monthly rebalanced portfolio that looks this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['6/30/2015','6/30/2015','6/30/2015','7/30/2015','7/30/2015','7/30/2015'],'Ticker': ['AAPL','MSFT','IBM','AAPL','MSFT','AMZN']})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

In particular, I would like to know for each month, how many of the positions in the portfolio were replaced. So for July it should show 1/3, since IBM was replaced with AMZN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pivot and use `shift` to compare:

```
pivoted = df.assign(rank=df.groupby('Date').cumcount()).pivot('Date','rank','Ticker')

(pivoted!=pivoted.shift()).sum(1)/pivoted.shape[1]
```

Output:

```
Date
2015-06-30    1.000000
2015-07-30    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the method provided above might return a wrong answer in some situations:

```
(pivoted!=pivoted.shift()).sum(1)/pivoted.shape[1]
```

Suppose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['6/30/2015','6/30/2015','6/30/2015','7/30/2015','7/30/2015','7/30/2015'],'Ticker': ['AAPL','MSFT','IBM','AAPL','IMB','ZXX']})
```

i.e. 'AAPL','MSFT','IBM' in June and 'AAPL','IMB','ZXX' in July, the answer should be 1/3, while above method will return 2/3.
(not enough reputation to comment above answer)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35326618)